# Any advantages of PyQt4.QtXml over native xml libraries?

Tags: python, xml, qt, pyqt4, qtxml

I am developing an application in PyQt, and one of its features involves dealing with XML.

I have code from other projects lying around, and they are mostly based on `xml.dom.minidom`, with which I have some familiarity. But since my application is already "immersed" in PyQt code for lots of things, I considered giving Qt's framework some consideration.

Well, it looks quite interesting, well documented, but somewhat overwhelming, so the question is:

> Would there be a good reason to prefer (Py)Qt xml framework over `minidom` or other native python XML library?

Things that I think would count as "good reason":

- More powerful API and/or programming model;
- Classes that would be more useful and overall easier to work with compared with native python modules;
- Significantly better integration with the rest of PyQt code, its event model, and the like (currently I am focused on the Graphics Framework, but I think the Model/View Programming is promising);

I ask because I would not like to go up the learning curve just to realize it was not actually needed.

Comment: What would count as a "good reason"? It sounds like you're inviting opinions, unless you can be much more specific about what you need to achieve. Does `xml.dom.minidom` lack some features that you need? Are there bugs or performance issues that you can't work around? It sounds like pointless code-churn to make the switch, unless you have some concrete goal in mind. Then again, maybe you're just interested in learning a new API - in which case, you already have your good reason...

Comment: @ekhumoro Actually I would prefer _not_ having to learn a new API, but my problem is: how would I know if I don't study it? So the reason for my question is to give the oportunity to anyone who already faced the same decision to come up and say "don't think twice, go for it, because of this and that", or rather the contrary, "don't even bother, they do the same things, only with different APIs" or something. Currently I feel I don't have the information to decide, and acquiring this information might have a cost that I would not be willing to pay.

Comment: But what real decision are you trying make? So far, it sounds like you're just asking people to recommend an xml library - which you know is off-topic, right?

Comment: @ekhumoro Well, I was not one hundred percent aware if it was off-topic or not. I have the impression of seeing such kind of question around all the time, sometimes with very useful and interesting answers. But anyway, if it's the case, then I'll have to accept what moderators decide.

Comment: Personally, I've seen a lot of pyqt projects and I've never seen any pyqt code that used QtXML.  In fact, I've never seen any Qt code that used it either.

Comment: SO discourages questions about technology selection. The justification given is that the answers tend to be opinion-based. Of course technology selection should in principle be objective and rational and not opinion-based at all; but objective decisions on choosing technology require much more analysis of requirements than is possible in an SO post.

Comment: @BrendanAbel. Searching for `qt xml` on SO gets nearly 2000 hits, so there seem to be plenty of people using it. Also, [nulledge](http://nullege.com/) finds a few pyqt projects, like [leoeditor](http://leoeditor.com/) and [PCode](http://github.com/fortharris/Pcode).

Comment: I feel the question you are asking is really "why does the PyQt XML library exist when there are other xml libraries?" The answer is that Qt is a C++ library, and so the XML part was created in that context (C++ doesn't have a built-in XML parser like python does). You'll probably find there are a few parts of Qt that aren't particularly useful in Python. So feel free to use whatever you want without concern.

Comment: @three_pineapples, thanks for your comment. It actually feels very much like an answer ;o)